# webpage redirects to localhost

Tags: codeigniter, web-development-server

I am new to the world of web development. I have a website hosted. When I login it should take me to `"member_dashboard.php"`. It redirects to this page on localhost. If I modify the localhost path, the remote redirect gets affected. I am using codeigniter as the framework. "base_url" is left blank. I tried setting the base url with the full http path of my index page still cannot fix it.

`$config['base_url'] = '';`

Answer (score 0):

Do this changes as well

In `config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "";//default controller name
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

In `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

In `.htaccess` (Place outside `application` folder)

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
  </IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your website name is example.com
So just keep
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/'; 
under your application>config>config.php

Believe me your problem will solve because I personal did it and its working.
Have any questions or clarification, please let me know.

Thanks,
Amzad

Answer (score 0):

The value on this key must be different on each environment. It file can not be included on control version. Considerate set it on .gitignore

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
//localhost environment
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
//other env
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mypublicsite.com/';
```