# error "404 Page Not Found" in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter.
I have a class MY_Controller in '/core/MY_Controller.php'

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
   function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo $controller = $this->uri->segment(1);
    }
}
```

And class Login.php in \controllers\admin\Login.php

```
class Login extends MY_Controller{
   function index()
    {
        echo 'login';
    }
}
```

When i get error 404 when access http://localhost/codeigniter/admin/login/ in browser.

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong? Thanks C.

Comment: One more thing controller class name should be `class_Controller` in you `Login` case it should be `Login_Controller`;

Comment: Thanks for reply, i typed wrong in this question, sorry !

Comment: Problem  is this there is no directory support for controllers in codeigniter;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TRICK**

Add this code to your `config` file at the top may this code helps you

```
function __autoload($class)
{
  if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
  {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . '.php'))
        {
              include $file;
        }
  }
}
```

**METHOD**

You need to set Prefix in your `config` file

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

**htaccess**

```
     RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**ROUTES**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'YOUR_CONTROLLER';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin'] = "admin/login";
```

Comment: is login controller work with extends CI_  intead of MY_ ? @hyphens2

Comment: no, i try but it's not working.
I'm get error in 5m32s when i follow this video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QicydizTCOs&list=PLShhnaMcz_Zy1ipos-PUP9UrJauBkKUza&index=4&nohtml5=False

Comment: are defined ur base urls ??

Comment: it's worked, thanks so much !

i placed .htaccess file in directory \codeiginter to remove index.php, why http://localhost/codeigniter/admin/login/ not working ?

Comment: yup you need to remove index.php from ur controller :) wait i edit with mine htaceess file @hyphens2

Comment: thanks, but when i change my .htaccess file, and when i type http://localhost/codeigniter/admin/login, it's return become http://localhost/dashboard/

Comment: it's still return localhost/dashboard

Comment: is ur controller palced in application folder ??

Comment: in your route file add default controller and admin controller wait edited @hyphens2

Comment: Can you teamview to fix it for me because seem i spending your time, sr !

Comment: i am on mobile :) not able to use team view no problem for tym its interesting to learn new things for me and u @hyphens2

Comment: i edited route.php 

`$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['administrator'] = 'admin\login';`
I have Home.php in controller folder
http://pastebin.com/DDYitv2Q

Comment: change $route['administrator'] to $route['admin']  = admin/login and use forward slash @hyphens2

Comment: yup, i changed to `$route['admin'] = 'admin/login';` but it's still return http://localhost/dashboard/

Comment: when i editted .htaccess file and type http://localhost/codeigniter/admin/login, it's get error `404 Page Not Found. The page you requested was not found.`
but type http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/admin/login it's still working

Comment: i do follow this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: I changed, It still `404 Page Not Found`

Comment: @hyphens2 after any change in htaccess please restart ur apache server

Comment: :o      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284671/webpage-redirects-to-localhost

Comment: it start error when change `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter'` to `$config['base_url'] = '';` and `$autoload['helper'] = array('url','file','date','common');` to `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`
:) so i return first default. it difficult to understand although try more tuts but can;t remove index.php in url , LOL

Comment: maybe i download new codeigniter framework and start copy my class and reconfig, hope it's work

Comment: :) gudluck @hyphens2

Comment: it's worked :) 
my teacher say Install new windows is the simplest way to solve any error !

Comment: @hyphens2 I would propose `spl_autoload_register()` function. Explanation why could be found is in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424255/error-in-installing-omnipay-in-codeigniter/32425877#answer-32425877).